# knockoutjs reusable template control

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to create a reusable custom control in knockoutjs for this I have written following code in knockout.When user click on NF field textbox toggle to dropdownlist and vice versa.I want to pass data from viewmodel to knockout component and want to fetch their data in viewmodel.

```
ko.components.register('nf-editor', {
    viewModel: function (params) {
        var self = this;
        self.options = ko.observableArray(params && params.data || '');
        self.text=ko.observable(params && params.text || '');
        self.optionText=ko.observable(params && params.optionText || '');
        self.optionsCaption=ko.observable(params && params.optionsCaption || '');


        self.isNF = ko.observable(false);
        self.change = function () {
            self.isNF(!self.isNF());
        };

    },
    template: '<input maxlength="50" data-bind="textInput:text,visible:!isNF()" type="text" /> ' +  '<select name="rep_prefix_nfddl" data-bind="optionsText:optionText,options: options,visible:isNF" />'+
  '<a href="#" data-bind="click:change">NF</a>'

});

function VM() {
    var self = this;
    self.options = ["Test", "Test1"];
    self.optionText="Demo";
    self.text="Test";

}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());


<div data-bind='component: { name: "nf-editor",  params: { data: options,text:text }
}'></div>

<div data-bind="text:text"/>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/santosh_singh/38bLt97q/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For communication between ViewModels and Components, use [ko.postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox).

From your fiddle, you can try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/newuserjs/38bLt97q/4/).

```
ko.components.register('nf-editor', {
    viewModel: function (params) {
        this.options = ko.observableArray(params && params.data || '');

        var self = this;
        self.isNF = ko.observable(false);
        self.change = function () {
            self.isNF(!self.isNF());
        };
        self.selectedInputValue = params.text;
        self.selectedOptionsValue = params.selectedOptionsValue;
    },
    template: '<input maxlength="50" data-bind="visible:!isNF(), textInput: selectedInputValue" type="text" /> ' +  '<select name="rep_prefix_nfddl" data-bind="value: selectedOptionsValue, options: options,visible:isNF" />'+
  '<a href="#" data-bind="click:change">NF</a>'

});

function VM() {
    var self = this;
    self.options = ["C#", "DSA"];
    self.text = ko.observable();
    self.selectedOptionsValue = ko.observable();
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

Answer (score 1):

How about if, instead of `visible` bindings for swapping elements, you make the elements into templates, and swap templates?

The parent and component can share observables such as `options` and `text` and any other observables you want to include in the component parameters.

```js
ko.components.register('nf-editor', {
  viewModel: function(params) {
    var self = this;
    self.options = params.options;
    self.text = params.text;
    self.isNF = ko.observable(false);
    self.change = function() {
      self.isNF(!self.isNF());
    };
    self.whichControl = ko.computed(function() {
      return self.isNF() ? 'select-template' : 'input-template';
    });
  },
  template: '<!-- ko template: whichControl --><!-- /ko -->' +
  '<template id="select-template">' +
  '  <select name="rep_prefix_nfddl" data-bind="options: options" />' +
  '</template>' +
  '<template id="input-template">' +
  '  <input maxlength="50" type="text" data-bind="value: text"/>' +
  '</template>' +
  '<a href="#" data-bind="click:change">NF</a>'

});

function VM() {
  var self = this;
  self.options = ko.observableArray(["C#", "DSA"]);
  self.text = ko.observable('initial');
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind='component: { name: "nf-editor",  params: { options: options, text: text }}'>
</div>
```

Comment: @Santosh I've updated my answer so the templates are inside the component.